# Using template class in constructor

Tags: generics, kotlin

Here is the minimal example of my situation:

```
class Foo<T>(val list: List<Any>) {
    init {
        list.filterIsInstance<T>().forEach { ... } // error
    }
}
```

Naturally, this doesn't compile:

`Cannot use 'T' as reified type parameter. Use a class instead.`

What is the idiomatic solution to this kind of situation? It sounds like the compiler is suggesting a `KClass<T>` as a constructor parameter, but what does that usage look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple issues here. First, you have an error that you specified, because type pameter `T` of your class `Foo` is not *reified*. So, you would need the keyword **`reified`** where the type parameter is declared. But then, you would need an **`inline`** function in order to be able to do that (because of the JVM limitations, which Kotlin should support). The problem is, you cannot make constructors to be **`inline`** in Kotlin.

The closest you can get to what you need is the following:

```
class Foo<T>(val list: List<T>) {

    init {
        list.forEach { println(it) }
    }

    companion object {

        inline fun <reified T> create(list: List<Any>): Foo<T> {
            return Foo(list.filterIsInstance<T>())
        }
    }
}
```

The above assumes you just need to obtain all the elements that are instances of some class from the list, and work only with those elements inside your `Foo` class.

**UPDATE:** Even though you want the type parameter on the instance of `Foo` itself to be reified, this is simply not possible in Kotlin (as is specified above, due to JVM limitations).

So you need to ensure the type passed at creation is the same? Fine. Then there is no other way other than specifying an additional argument:

```
class Foo<T>(val list: List<Any>, `class`: Class<T>) {
    init {
        list.filter { `class`.isInstance(it) }.forEach { println(it) }
    }
}
```

You did not specify what you were going to do with the list obtained, and why you needed the type strictly the same, but I personally wouldn't bother with that and used the first variant.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your code, but this isn't a solution to the problem stated. Your templates are both named `T`, but refer to potentially different things. I want my `init` to ensure that `T` is the same type passed at creation, which you aren't doing. Essentially, I want a reified type `T` for a `Foo<T>`. How can I get that at construction?

Comment: @EntangledLoops I updated my answer, but frankly, unless you specify what you need these specific requirements for, we can play this guessing game until the cows come home, and yet you'll never be satisfied with the answer.

Comment: I'm not sure why you think the use case matters. It's a simple question: How do I access/use a template class in a constructor in Kotlin? Your updated answer addresses that.

Comment: An example use case is a class that accepts a list that may contain types `T` and `U`. You want to perform an operation on only the `T` elements at init time.

Comment: @EntangledLoops The first variant allows you to do that (perform operation on only the `T` elements). What was not clear to me (still isn't, actually), was why you needed strict guarantee that type `T` of the constructor was the same as type `T` of the `create` method -- just don't ever call the constructor directly! (Unfortunately, Kotlin does not allow making the constructor private or even internal in this case.)

Comment: Yes, I see your point. Thanks for the answer. I was hoping to accomplish this directly with the constructor, but I'll use a factory method if necessary.